# Erotica novel trilogy set on Mars, potentially a parody of the Mars Trilogy by Kim Stanley Robinson

Tags: story-identification, mars

I remember reading a part of a semi-erotic novel in the mid 1990's from a UK library that for a long time I thought was part of Kim Stanley Robinson's *Mars Trilogy*.

I believe that the novel was part of a trilogy that used colour in someway in it's title and was set on Mars, hence the confusion with the Mars Trilogy. The novels had erotic elements, but I would say they were very tame. They could possibly by parody novels of the *Mars Trilogy* itself.

Parts that I remember are:

- Mars has a native population of humanoid creatures.
- These Martians have tentacles that are either sex organs or are pleasure organs for the Martians.
- I don't believe that Mars is fully teraformed but humans are able to travel the surface relatively easily.
- Humans are second class citizens on Mars, with the Martians being the dominant species in the planet.
- The human protagonist of the novels is trying to navigate Mars for some reason, but is regularly stopped in his tracks by various means.
- I think the channels on Mars are filled with water or some other substance that allows them to be used for navigation with boat like vehicles.
- I believe the leader Martian described in the spoiler tags below lives in a pyramid type structure that is at the start/end of a journey the protagonist takes along the channels of Mars.
- The novel would have been available in a UK library in the mid to late 1990's.

Adult content included below

> The only sex scene I remember was were the protagonist has to perform oral sex on a creature that is the king/leader of an area/city on Mars.
> The leader requires the protagonist to suck on a tentacle so that the protagonist will be allowed to continue on their journey.
>  While the protagonist does not want to do this, he is not forced and doesn't seem to think such a liaison between a Human and Martian is wrong.

Comment: That almost sounds like a novelisation of the classic Infocom text adventure "The Leather Goddesses of Phobos".

Comment: It sounds the sort of thing Andrew J. Offutt/John Cleve would write, though a quick glance through his bibliography fails to see anything matching your question.